# Do I need a comma for this quotation?

Tags: punctuation, commas, writing, direct-speech

Do I need a comma before the quotation, or can I write without it? This is the sentence:

> Someone, not so long ago said, “Simply put: If you’re doing business with the biggest companies in the world, you’re not just spending time in New York, London, and Hong Kong”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/punctuation/punctuation-in-direct-speech):

> If direct speech comes after the information about who is speaking, you should use a comma to introduce the piece of speech, placed before the first inverted comma:
>
> Steve replied, ‘No problem.’

So yes, you need a comma there.